# PyQt: ReturnPressed method on a lineEdit is connecting to the wrong button

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a lineEdit and three buttons; next, back and finish. If the user presses enter whilst the focus is on the lineEdit, I want it to be the same as pressing next. This is my code in the **init** method:

```
    self.clfdlg.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(lambda: self.clfdlg.next.click())
    self.clfdlg.next.clicked.connect(lambda: self.next())   
    self.clfdlg.back.clicked.connect(lambda: self.back())
    self.clfdlg.finish.clicked.connect(lambda: self.finish())
```

Instead of the next() method being called, the finish() method is being called. I have also tried:

```
    self.clfdlg.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(lambda: self.next())
```

This has the same result of calling the finish() method. Has this happened to anyone before, I'd really appreciate some advise as to where I am going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If `clfdlg` is a `QDialog`, you're probably falling foul of the [default](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#default-prop) property of the buttons. Try explicitly clearing this property on all the relevant buttons:

```
    self.clfdlg.next.setAutoDefault(False)
    self.clfdlg.next.setDefault(False)
    self.clfdlg.back.setAutoDefault(False)
    # etc ...
```